# How to match regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
describe aws_security_group({:group_id=>"sg-ezsrzerzer", :vpc_id=>"vpc-zfds54zef4s"}) do
```

I try to filter the `sg-ezsrzerzer` out of it (so I want to filter on start `sg-` till double quote). I'm using python

I currently have:

```
import re
a = 'describe aws_security_group({:group_id=>"sg-ezsrzerzer", :vpc_id=>"vpc-zfds54zef4s"}) do'
test = re.findall(r'\bsg-.*\b', a)
print(test)
```

output is

```
['sg-ezsrzerzer", :vpc_id=>"vpc-zfds54zef4s"}) do']
```

How do I only get `['sg-ezsrzerzer']`?

Comment: Yse `r'\bsg-[^"]+'`

Comment: Or like `(?<=")sg-\w+(?=")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `(?<=group_id=\>").+?(?=\")` would work nicely if the goal is to extract the `group_id` value within a given string formatted as in your example.

`(?<=group_id=\>")` Looks behind for the sub-string `group_id=>"` before the string to be matched.

`.+?` Matches one or more of any character [lazily](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy).

`(?=\")` Looks ahead for the character `"` following the match (effectively making the expression `.+` match any character except a closing `"`).

If you **only** want to extract sub-strings where the `group_id` starts with `sg-` then you can simply add this to the matching part of the pattern as follows `(?<=group_id=\>")sg\-.+?(?=\")`

```py
import re

s = 'describe aws_security_group({:group_id=>"sg-ezsrzerzer", :vpc_id=>"vpc-zfds54zef4s"}) do'

results = re.findall('(?<=group_id=\>").+?(?=\")', s)

print(results)
```

**Output**

```
['sg-ezsrzerzer']
```

Of course you could alternatively use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead of `re.findall` to find the first instance of a sub-string matching the above pattern in a given string - depends on your use case I suppose.

```py
import re

s = 'describe aws_security_group({:group_id=>"sg-ezsrzerzer", :vpc_id=>"vpc-zfds54zef4s"}) do'

result = re.search('(?<=group_id=\>").+?(?=\")', s)

if result:
    result = result.group()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
'sg-ezsrzerzer'
```

If you decide to use `re.search` you will find that it returns `None` if there is no match found in your input string and an [`re.Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) object if there is - hence the `if` statement and call to `s.group()` to extract the matching string if present in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\bsg-.*\b` matches too much as the `.*` will match until the end of the string, and will then backtrack to the first word boundary, which is after the `o` and the end of string.

---

If you are using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) you can also use a capture group instead of lookarounds and the group value will be in the result.

```
:group_id=>"(sg-[^"\r\n]+)"
```

The pattern matches:

- `:group_id=>"` Match literally
- `(sg-[^"\r\n]+)` Capture **group 1** match `sg-` and  1+ times any char except `"` or a newline
- `"` Match the double quote

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UKLMEQ/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/03q94z)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r':group_id=>"(sg-[^"\r\n]+)"'
s = "describe aws_security_group({:group_id=>\"sg-ezsrzerzer\", :vpc_id=>\"vpc-zfds54zef4s\"}) do"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['sg-ezsrzerzer']
```

Answer (score 0):

Match until the first word boundary with `\w+`:

```py
import re
a = 'describe aws_security_group({:group_id=>"sg-ezsrzerzer", :vpc_id=>"vpc-zfds54zef4s"}) do'
test = re.findall(r'\bsg-\w+', a)
print(test[0])
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##JY3BCoMwEETvfsXiJUq1FGovgv2RWiSa1QasCbuxYkq/PdUWBmbgDTN2dQ8znUPQT2vIAWEkoQKhkDvSLYJcuGHsZtJubQYys03e5c8braprzEOOnsnjrjiD8mW7P9lC7nvFl8JjX3D8SUEZETlktz0QHns9KTmOCYm63Wbq5SAykGlkSU8u2Xu30z0N4Qs).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  sg-                      'sg-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

**Results**: `g-ezsrzerzer`